Correct approach to convert std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> to std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Types...>>>
template <class... Types>
class Dataframe
{
public:
    Dataframe(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& input);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Types...>>> Data();

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Types...>>> data_;
};

template <class... Types>
std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Types...>>> Dataframe<Types...>::Data() {
    return data_;
}


std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> input = {{"2024-03-03", "1.3", "1"}, {"2024-04-04", "3.4", "10"}}

auto df = Dataframe<std::string, double, int>(input);
df.Data(); //expected output: {{"2024-03-03", "2024-04-04"}, {1.3, 3.4}, {1, 10}}


std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> input_2 = {{"2024-03-03", "1", "1", "2.3"}, {"2024-04-04", "3.4", "10", "1.2"}}
auto df_2 = Dataframe<std::string, int, double, double>(input_2); // Can also handle this 
df_2.Data(); //expected output: {{"2024-03-03", "2024-04-04"}, {1, 3}, {1.0, 10.0}, {2.3, 1.2}}  

I am trying to create a dataframe class with a dynamic type signature to handle multiple data types. I am new to templates (and c++ in general). I am trying to create a class similar to pandas dataframe so I can then get averages, rolling averages, etc. with the columns.

Is this the right approach? or would std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>> data_; be better?
If this is the right approach, since Dataframe<std::string, int, double> can vary in length, how can I create the std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Types...>>> data_ so when I loop over the input I can do something like below but how do I take the types into account here?

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < input[i].size(); ++j) {
        data_[i].push_back(input[i][j]);
    }
}

Not an expert in templates and keep getting errors.

Template errors can get really, really long, but including the errors you get from your code is very helpful both to potential answerers (who now don't have to make mock-up of your code in order to see those errors) and to future askers who can now find your question when searching for the errors.

Wait. You don't just want to pack a string into a variant. You want a string whose contents resemble a formatted double value to be converted to double, and a string whose contents rememble an integer to be converted to int. And somehow do it generically for any kind of type that might appear in Types? Plus, you want the result transposed, turning a 2x3 matrix into a 3x2 one?

What do you know about Types? Do you know there is always going to be a string, double and int in the list? What other types do you expect there, and how would you parse a string into those types? Take a step back, describe the problem you are actually trying to solve rather than your proposed solution. As written, this sounds like an XY problem

Types will be at least 1 but can be n in size. Types can contain any Type but in my use case I only plan to use: int, double or strings (above I only said int or doubles but that was a typo). Adding overloading functions that convert the specific types can be added. But I am not sure how to access the the types in Types to do that. I am too new to c++.

What do you mean by "n columns"? How does n get into the picture? For your example input, what should the outcome be with Dataframe<std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string> or Dataframe<int, int, int, int, int>?

If you use std::variant, you won't be able to store "any type", only those that you specify as template arguments. You can then "ask" the variant what type it holds with std::holds_alternative, or use std::visit to invoke a function that is overloaded for all specified types. To be able to hold any type, you can use std::any and distinguish what is being held by typeid... But that won't be too convenient.

Dataframe<std::string, std::string, std::string. std::string, std::string> n would be 5 because there are 5 string types. input = {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, {"2.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0", "6.0"}, {"3", "4", "5", "6", "7"}}. Dataframe<std::string, std::string, std::string. std::string, std::string> would just be a transpose to {{"1", "2.0", "3"}, {"2", "3.0", "4"}, {"3", "4.0", "5"}, {"4", "5.0", "6"}, {"5", "6.0", "7"}}. Dataframe<int, int, int, int, int> would  be {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}}.

If you use std::variant, you won't be able to store "any type", only those that you specify as template arguments.  That is ok and what I meant, any type in the template argument. I'll give what you said a try, thanks!

If a) the number and type of columns (and so therefore rows in data_) is known at compile time, and b) Types may contain the same type more than once, then std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Types...>>> doesn't make much sense as a data structure. Perhaps you are looking for std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...> (that is, a tuple with one element for each column, which is a vector of values in that column). Or if you insist on double vector, then perhaps std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<std::string, double, int>>>. Kinda depends on what you plan to do next with this beast.

Why don't you just use an existing dataframe library, such as https://github.com/hosseinmoein/DataFrame? What specific functions fail to work with existing dataframe libraries? On the other hand, if you are new to templates, then the source code of https://github.com/hosseinmoein/DataFrame may be hard for you to consume, but you can still take a look and see if anything helps if you need to implement your own library.

As types are known, std::variant seems not needed, and using std::tuple seems to do the job:
template <class... Types>
class Dataframe
{
public:
    Dataframe(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& input)
    {
        auto make_frame = [](const std::vector<std::string>& v){
            assert(v.size() == sizeof...(Types));
            return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
                return std::tuple<Types...>(convert_to(std::type_identity<Types>{}, v[Is])...);
            }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>());
        };
        for (const auto& v : input) {
            data_.emplace_back(make_frame(v));
        }

    }
    std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>> Data() { return data_; }

private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>> data_;
};

You also want to transform std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>> into std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>:
template <typename... Types>
std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>
AoS2SoA(const std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>>& v)
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...> res;
    for (const auto& e : v)
    {
        [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
            (std::get<Is>(res).push_back(std::get<Is>(e)), ...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>());
    }
    return res;
}

Demo
